# Break very long lines with access to deeply nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, pep8

I access a deeply nested dictionary and want to break very long lines properly. Let's assume I have this and want to break the line to conform with [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). (The actual line is of course longer, this is just an example.)

```
some_dict['foo']['bar']['baz'] = 1
```

How would you break the line, assuming the whole

```
some_dict['foo']['bar']['baz']
```

does not fit on one line anymore? There are a lot of examples for breaking long lines, but I couldn't find one for this dictionary access based question.

**Update:** Please note that I want to **assign** something to that dictionary. The proposed duplicate only talks about getting a value from that kind of dictionary.

Comment: you can break lines by adding a `\\` at the end of the line

Comment: Having such deep dictionary accesses is probably a sign that you should refactor your code. Instead of inserting line breaks, I'd split the command into smaller pieces. E.g. `a = some_dict['foo']` followed by `a['bar']`, ...

Comment: I agree with @Felix but if you insist, I'd say just keep the long lines and have the linter ignore the line. Typically, you do that with an end comment of `# noqa`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's the solution I'm most happy with. It boils down to:

```
some_dict['foo']['bar']['baz'] = 1
```

is equal to

```
(some_dict['foo']['bar']['baz']) = 1
```

which you can break anywhere you want, like so:

```
(some_dict['foo']
          ['bar']['baz']) = 1
```

Which should be aligned with Pythons [preferred](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) way to break long lines, using Python's implied line continuation inside parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

If you are dealing with deeply nested dictionaries, you should consider another data structure, refactoring with tuple keys, or defining your path via a list.

Here's an example of the last option which helps specifically with PEP8:

```
from operator import getitem
from functools import reduce

def get_val(dataDict, mapList):
    return reduce(getitem, mapList, dataDict)

d = {'foo': {'bar': {}}}

*path, key = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

get_val(d, path)[key] = 1
```

Note that lists don't need line escapes between elements. This is perfectly fine:

```
*path, key = ['foo',
              'bar',
              'baz']
```