# Proper way of breaking line accessing dictionary

Tags: python, pep8

I am try to conform to `pep8` directives and therefore to break the following line:

```
   config_data_dict['foo']['bar']['foobarfoo'] \
        ['barfoobar'] = something_else
```

However I am getting the following warning now just after the `['foobarfoo']` section

> whitespace before '[' pep8(E211)

How should I properly break a line as the above (assuming I cannot brake it around `=`)?

Comment: It's ugly in my opinion, but I think you could avoid the PEP error if you broke one of the key strings in half. Won't work if the keys are variable names, though...

Comment: Put the line continuation character immediately after the `]` to suppress that warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parentheses seem to work:

```
(config_data_dict['foo']['bar']['foobarfoo']
 ['barfoobar']) = something_else
```

This also seems to be the recommended style according to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id19):

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation.

Comment: This would be my answer as well, you can put each key on it's own line, or wrap right at 79, it makes for pretty clean looking code

Comment: I personally don’t really like the parentheses like that just seems that’s an odd way to write a line when you rarely ever see parentheses used this way. Not saying it’s a bad answer just my preference.

Comment: there seems to be a lot of debate around this issue; in any case I opted for this solution;

Answer (score 1):

You could break inside the `[...]` (though I'm not really sure which would be considered more readable: breaking after the `[`, or before the `]`, or both):

```
config_data_dict[
    'foo'][
    'bar'][
    'foobarfoo'][
    'barfoobar'] = something_else
```

As a general rule, either put all the keys on the same line, or put each key on a separate line. This applies to the explicit parenthesization used in other answers, for example,

```
(config_data_dict
     ['foo']
     ['bar']
     ['foobarfoo']
     ['barfoobar']) = something_else
```

However, I would just use one or more temporary variables:

```
d = config_data_dict['foo']['bar']['foobarfoo']
d['barfoobar'] = something_else
```

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of ways you can do this but here’s my opinion on the 2 “best” ways. (I say best loosely as opinion and context do apply)

Using [`operator.setitem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.setitem). *(this is almost the same as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51320514/225020) but to me looks much more readable as it doesn’t have the leading parentheses)*

```
setitem(config_data_dict
    ['foo']['bar']['foobarfoo'],
    'barfoobar', something_else)
```

Or some prefer the `reduce` method with [`operator.getitem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.getitem). *(also alike [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51316815/225020) the reduce approach could be easier on the eyes if you’re getting REALLY deeply nested but I prefer the later as it’s not adding yet another somewhat unnecessary function into the mix)*

```
path = ['foo','bar','foobarfoo']
reduce(getitem, path, config_data_dict)['barfoobar'] = something_else
```

Or to allow for more nice indenting use `setitem` here too

```
setitem(reduce(getitem, path, config_data_dict),
    'barfoobar', something_else)
```

All of that being said, you could use shorter variable names, for instance `config_data_dict` really doesn’t need the dict at the end. It does make the variable more descriptive although I’m sure most should easily be able to discern that it’s a dict by how you’re accessing it.